# How to run gnuplot/latex from inside texshop?

Tags: tikz-pgf, gnuplot, plot, texshop

I was able to write a piece of code that drew a graph in `gnuplot` and then
using `tikz` embedded that into my TeX document and run it via `Texshop`. I am
not able to do that anymore. I need to run

```
pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex
```

For my graphs to appear properly. Is there some setting I can
enable in `TexShop` so I don't have to do this. I mean I want
to be able to just hit type set from inside `TexShop` to do this.
As I understand they have done away with the `--shell-escape` flag
in `TexShop` because of security vulnerabilities.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to go to `TeXShop/Preferences` and add the `--shell-escape` option to the `Engine` tab as shown here:

[image]

After restarting TeXShop, selecting `LaTeX` from the pull down will automatically have the `--shell-escape` option enabled.

Alternatively you can also create you own `.engine` files. An example of this is at [Problems with implementing glossary.engine in TeXShop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49095/problems-with-implementing-glossary-engine-in-texshop).  As egreg commented, with your own custom engine it is clear to you that are enabling `--shell-escape`, especially if you name it something like `LaTeX w ShellEscape`.

This will enable `--shell-escape` but you still need to ensure that you indded have `gnuplot` installed. As I mentioned in an earlier answer at [Generating graphs with gnuplot (Gnuplot, LaTeX and tkz-fct)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/generating-graphs-with-gnuplot-gnuplot-latex-and-tkz-fct) you should have a look at [this gnuplot tutorial](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs/tutorial.pdf) and ensure that gnuplot is working.

Comment: The alternative engine is, in my opinion, the best route. Just the warning is not sufficient as users tend to get annoyed and are tempted to disable it. Choosing the engine with active shell escape should be a conscious decision.

Comment: Well I did this but its still the same. The graphs don't get graphed. Also, what do you mean pull down?. I do not have an option for PdfLaTeX in my pull down. It has:

Plain Tex, BibTeX, LaTeX etc. But not PdfLaTeX

Comment: @user54755: Yes it is `LaTeX` in `TeXShop`. Have corrected that. Also you need to make sure that you have `gnuplot` working -- see updated answer.

Comment: @PeterGrill. Thanks so much for your help peter. Gnuplot does work. I checked from the command line and then running my gnuplot tex file using the command line with the command : pdflatex --shell-escape foo.tex. The graphs appear properly then. But when I try to use texshop to typeset it,  the problem occurs. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user54755 Did you restart `TeXShop`? If that does not resolve the issue don't know I can help without more info. Can you post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)  of a sample file that runs. Also, check the log files, perhaps there is some information there.

Comment: @PeterGrill: It works now :). May be I didn't restart texshop before. But I'm pretty sure I did. In any case it works now. Also, what is the difference between the default scripts : PdfTeX and TeX+Dvi? Which one is more appropriate for things like plotting/tikz/gnuplot??

Comment: I would recommend using `LaTeX` and going directly to PDF. But you may want to search this site for a similar question and if you don't find one, posting a new question.