# pgfplots / gnuplot: How to draw a 3D two-parametric function

Tags: pgfplots, gnuplot

I want to plot a 2-parametric surface function

```
set parametric
splot cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)*cos(v),sin(v)
```

(Hint: If I just put it into gnuplot it works.)

I guess that special settings in pgfplots are necessary for such a special function.

So: Why does the 2nd example plot nothing? 
Which options do I have to set here in pgfplots?

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}

\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=7cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[title=Works]
\addplot3[] 
gnuplot{sin(x)*sin(y)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,]
\begin{axis}[title={Works not - what do I have to set?}]
\addplot3[]
gnuplot {
set parametric
splot cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)*cos(v),sin(v) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Should give sth. like this:

[image]

Comment: When you use external programs like `gnuplot` or `sage` you need to run the external program as well and then compile a second time in LaTeX. Have you done that? If so what does the `.log` file tell you? If you haven't run gnuplot then your `.log` file will say something about the current plot has no coordinates or have been filtered away. See my comment [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30889/generating-graphs-with-gnuplot-gnuplot-latex-and-tkz-fct) for someone with similar problem.

Comment: @DJP    My problem is not that it never works with gnuplot, but that it doesn't work with gnuplot here. I didn't say anything like that either, on the other hand I didn't say it wasn't said either. So please, see my edit.

Comment: @DJP The problem is probably not the compilation, but the settings in pgfplots or gnuplot. I assumed it was obvious - my fault.
 Have you tested the example and does it output something - I don't think so, otherwise you would not have written general information about the gnuplot compilation process.

Comment: In my comment, I asked (provided you were compiling properly) for what your log file indicates. On my computer, the log file says: "PGFPlots: reading {STEX.pgf-plot.table}
Package pgfplots Warning: the current plot has no coordinates (or all have been
 filtered away) on input line 19.
 [warning /pgfplots/warning/plot without coordinates]
Package pgfplots Warning: You have an axis with empty range (in direction z). Replacing it with a default range and clearing all plots. on input line 20.". My gnuplot version is 5.0 (current version is 5.4) so your log could be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a `.gnuplot` file that you can look at to see which code is being passed to Gnuplot.

For your case you get

```
set table "test.pgf-plot.table"; set format "%.5f"
set format "%.7e";; set samples 25, 25; set dummy x,y; set isosamples 25, 25; splot [x=-5:5] [y=-5:5]  set parametric splot cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)*cos(v),sin(v) ;
```

As you can see you get `splot <domain settings> <your code>`, meaning that Gnuplot gets

```
splot ... set parametric
```

which doesn't work because after `splot` and options there should be a function expression. You can also see the error from Gnuplot in the `.log` file, it says

```
"test.pgf-plot.gnuplot" line 2: undefined variable: set
```

where the `set` in question is that in `set parametric`.

To fix this you can use the `parametric` key on the TikZ side of things instead of `set parametric`:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=7cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,]
\begin{axis}[title={Works not - what do I have to set?}]
\addplot3[]
gnuplot [parametric=true] {
cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)*cos(v),sin(v) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you can use `raw gnuplot`. In that case you need to set the domain and sample size in the Gnuplot code instead of the `pgfplots` being passed on:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {shell: yes}
\documentclass[margin=3mm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, width=7cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize,]
\begin{axis}[title={Works not - what do I have to set?}]
\addplot3[]
gnuplot [raw gnuplot] {
set parametric;
splot cos(u)*cos(v),sin(u)*cos(v),sin(v) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking good. Is there a way to get better help- / surface-lines?

Comment: @cis Don't really know. The domain and sample size affects the look and number of the lines though, so you can try fiddling with that. (For the first version, e.g. `\addplot3[samples=32, samples y=10,domain=0:2*pi] ...`, for the second one whatever Gnuplot the settings are for changing those things.)

Comment: I think, the second thing is the problem: find good gnuplot options. pgfplots-gnuplot does not create the same picture as plain-gnuplot does.

Comment: @cis Well you shouldn't necessarily expect that either. `pgfplots` only uses Gnuplot to calculate a file with values, the visualization of those values is entirely done by `pgfplots`.